# Python 3: passing the changing value of a variable to a function in an imported library of functions

Tags: python, import, global

Noob here. I have just learned that "global" applies only within a module, and that fact has created a problem. The solutions on stackoverflow to similar problems are beyond my ken and seem overkill for what I am trying to do.

I have a function, ch(a, b), that uses a variable called "str_name," which is set to global in the main module (test.py). The function works fine there. str_name can be changed at will within test.py and the function works. But when moved to my library of functions, str_name is not received by ch(a, b).

I will put the code below. First some code to show the function's desired use (which, again, works when the function is in test.py). The function enables me to economize in coding. I am reformatting HTML, so I do dozens of search and replaces on only one or two variables. Instead of writing:

```
my_variable = my_variable.replace(v1, v2)
```

I can write:

```
ch(v1, v2)
```

Of course, it can only do that once the default is set to my_variable, and I would want to be able to change that to different variables at different places in the script. So the overall idea is to code this way:

```
str_name = 'my_first_variable'
ch(v1, v2)
ch('this is a literal', 'this is another literal')
ch(v5, v6)
str_name = 'my_next_variable'
ch(v14, v15)
ch(v102, v110)
```

etc.
--which makes possible:

```
sar_batch_for_myvar = [[v2, v1], [v5, v7], ['foo', 'bar']]
str_name = 'myvar'
for item in sar_batch_for_myvar:
   ch(item[0], item[1])
```

Then onto dictionaries of batches keyed by the name of the variable.

Here's the code that works, except when ch(a, b) has been imported:

```
def ch(a, b): 
   global str_name
   try:
      globals()[str_name] = globals()[(str_name)].replace(a, b)
   except NameError:
      print('   ***str_name must be in quotes! (e.g., \'s\' not s)?\n\n')
      return

global str_name
str_name = 's'
s = 'xyz'
print('s before =', s)
ch('x', '***')
ch('z', 'qqq')
print('s after =', s)
```

Comment: Really, don't do this.

Comment: Why not? And by 'this' you mean the whole move to ch(a, b)?

Comment: I mean using global variables and changing them magically.

Comment: Oh, fine. I picked that up off another stackoverflow thread. Is there a Pythonic way of dynamically making the function do str_to_change = 'myvar' then later str_to_change = 'mynext_var' etc.? I tried for hours with exec(code) and separately with def ch(a, b, str_to_change=None) plus an if test for it being None.

Comment: You get the idea of what I'm after, right?

Comment: How are the variables that correspond to `str_name` created?  You say you are reformatting html, so are they the contents of files that are read from disk? Or downloaded?  Or are they hard-coded in your module?

Comment: str_name is a place-holder for any variable that I put into any Python script. It's short for "the name of this string-variable." I'm not sure if that answers what you are asking.